# Moving from .Net 2 -> 3.5 SP1 WindowsForms: WindowsForms ControlDesigner / CollectionEditor missing ?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, .net-3.5, collectioneditor

I'm preparing to move some project from .Net 2.0 to 3.5SP1. I've noticed, that for some UI Controls the ControlDesigner / CollectionEditor Class seems to be missing in 3.5 ( ClientProfile ). What is the best practice to convert / replace these depencies or must I consider a complete rewrite of these components ? The error occured when switching the projects target framework from 2.0 to 3.5 without changing anything on the sourcecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I did a repair install of .net 3.5 sp1 which solved the problem. Nevertheless one question is left open:

I have an assembly with controls which include designer support. If I want to deploy the client profile only, I would have to make a separate assembly with the designer support only of certain controls, to be able to ship the application using these controls without having the need to deploy the full .Net package. ? Or if the designers are not used at runtime by the application, can I deploy the client profile ?

Comment: You need to move the designer support into a separate assembly. You can then use that assembly on your developer's machines, but you don't have to deploy it with your application. See this page for detailed instructions: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WinFormsCustomCtrl

Answer (score 1):

Designers should be missing in the ClientProfile. Do you think clients ever need the designers? 
Just use the complete 3.5 installation for development.

Comment: hmm, but what happens when I'm deploying an assembly which is marked as full framework ? Can I still deploy it with the client profile, when the designers are not used in the deploy version?
And it doesn't solves the problem. I switched back to full profile, but VS still show's errors about the missing classes ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the UI Controls self written, third-party-controls or the basic controls delivered with .NET itself?

If you just use the controls delivered with .NET it should work or sth. went wrong with the installation of the visual studio? Which VS-Version do you use?

Comment: I've the complete source code available and use VS2008SP1. So everything should work out okay, I think. But as I'm looking at the project references, the System.Design seems to be broken. The other ones seem still .Net 2.0. Should a project completely new created rather than simply switching the target framework ?

Comment: okay, I tried to remove all references from the project and wanted to readd the 3.5.1 ones, but for some reason VS doesn't show's them in the project...

Comment: hmm, removing and readding the references didn't helped. Question: how should the standard reference version numbers like System.Windows.Forms be: 2.0 or 3.5 ? It looks like, the lowest compatible version number is shown in the reference and the doesn't exist a higher version as 2.0 for System.Windows.Forms.